# Calling non-static method from another file/class

Tags: c#, non-static

I apologize in advance because I imagine this is a duplicate question but I've been searching for an answer for about an hour and I've yet to find one that resolves my problem.

Basically, I'm trying to call a non-static method from another file and class. My code is as follows:

`Form1.cs`:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {        
        public void SwapPositions()
        {
            text1.Location = new Point(73, 101);
            label1.Location = new Point(12, 111);
        }
     }
}
```

I'm trying to call the function like this but it does not work:

`Settings.cs`:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Settings : Form
    {
// some code //
                Form1 t = new Form1();
                t.SwapPositions();
     }
}
```

Could anyone explain to me why this doesn't work and how to change my code so as to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `Form1 t = new Form1()` it creates a new form. To invoke the `SwapPositions` Method on your form do this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Settings : Form
    {
        Form1 frm = null;
        public Settings(Form1 frm)
        {
            this.frm = frm;
        }
        public void MethodWhereSwapPositionsGetsInvoked()
        {
            frm.SwapPositions();
        }
     }
}
```

And create a instance of `Settings` with this:

```
Settings settings = new Settings(this);
```